# node-ews Update email to mark as read

Tags: node.js, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, node-ews

I'm using "node-ews" library version 3.5.0, but when I try to update any property I get the following error:

```
{
   "ResponseMessages":{
      "UpdateItemResponseMessage":{
         "attributes":{
            "ResponseClass":"Error"
         },
         "MessageText":"An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
         "ResponseCode":"ErrorInternalServerError",
         "DescriptiveLinkKey":0,
         "Items":null
      }
   }
}
```

I'm trying to mark email as read using the following code:

```
const markFolderAsRead = async (ews, id, changeKey) => {
  const args = {
    attributes: {
      MessageDisposition: "SaveOnly",
    },
    ItemChanges: {
      ItemChange: {
        ItemId: {
          attributes: {
            Id: id,
            ChangeKey: changeKey,
          },
        },
        Updates: {
          SetItemField: {
            FieldURI: {
              attributes: {
                FieldURI: "message:IsRead",
              },
              Message: {
                IsRead: true,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
  await ews.run("UpdateItem", args).then((result) => {
    console.log("email read:", JSON.stringify(result));
  });
};
```

I tried several modifications, including trying to update another fields, but none of it worked.
I followed this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/updateitem-operation
And the lib doesn't show any example of it, but when I change the json to a wrong "soap" construction the error show different messages, or even if I do not pass any of the parameters required as "ChangeKey".
So, maybe this error is something relate to microsoft ews soap construction that I'm missing parameters, or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working!

My JSON was wrong. The `FieldURI` was finishing after the message attribute, it should be before.

Correct JSON:

```
const args = {
    attributes: {
      MessageDisposition: "SaveOnly",
      ConflictResolution: "AlwaysOverwrite",
      SendMeetingInvitationsOrCancellations: "SendToNone",
    },
    ItemChanges: {
      ItemChange: {
        ItemId: {
          attributes: {
            Id: id,
            ChangeKey: changeKey,
          },
        },
        Updates: {
          SetItemField: {
            FieldURI: {
              attributes: {
                FieldURI: "message:IsRead",
              },
            },
            Message: {
              IsRead: "true",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
```